# iOS 7-only: NSMapTable crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash

I'm keeping something like memory-cache in `NSMapTable`:

```
// check for nils
if (key && image) {
    // set object to NSMapTable
    [_mapTable setObject:object forKey:key]; // crash
}
```

Unfortunately, lately I've got some problems with this method. Crash happens rather rarely, only on iOS 7. Crashlog indicates it happens at above line and shows more details:

```
-- Crashed: com.apple.root.default-priority ---
SIGABRT ABORT at 0x123456789

--- call stack ---
0    
libsystem_kernel.dylib  
__pthread_kill + 8
1
libsystem_pthread.dylib 
pthread_kill + 58
2
libsystem_c.dylib   
abort + 76
3    
libsystem_malloc.dylib  
free + 382
4
Foundation  
-[NSConcreteMapTable grow] + 546
5
Foundation  
-[NSConcreteMapTable setObject:forKey:] + 140
```

In fact, only 4 & 5 gives any info. I can't figure what's wrong in here. Because it happens in iOS7 only, maybe it's an Apple bug? Any ideas what can be the reason?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm seeing it happen too, pretty rarely, a couple of times a day for many users.

Comment: @Dima Same for me, didn't find a solution as for now. Please answer here if you find any solution :)